# Zend Framework documentation, exceptions

Tags: zend-framework, exception

I'm having trouble finding my way around Zend Framework documentation.

I'm currently using the "query" member function of the Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql class, and want to find out what exceptions it might throw. I've looked at http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_Db/Adapter/Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract.html#query , however there seems to be no info about it there. Oh I'm using version Zend Framework 1.10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`Zend_Exception`](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.exception.using.html) documentation says:

> The documentation for each Zend
>   Framework component and class will
>   contain specific information on which
>   methods throw exceptions, the
>   circumstances that cause an exception
>   to be thrown, and the various
>   exception types that may be thrown.

You are looking at the wrong API documentation. You need to look at the docs for [`Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract` query method](http://framework.zend.com/apidoc/core/Zend_Db/Adapter/Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract.html#query), which `Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql` extends - and an exception is mentioned there:

**throws**: `Zend_Db_Adapter_Exception` To re-throw `PDOException`.